# Exception when updating object containing collection of sub objects

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have `Account` and `RefreshToken` objects:

```
public class Account
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
        ...
    }

public class RefreshToken
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

`DBContext`:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Logic to create `RefreshToken` and add it to `Account` object (`_context` is the instance of my `DataContext`):

```
account.RefreshTokens.Add(newRefreshToken);
_context.Update(account);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

My `RefreshTokens` table created by EF tools contains foreign key `AccountId` that points to the parent `Account` object that contains the collection of `RefreshToken` objects. When I execute `_context.SaveChanges()` the framework throws an exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.'

Inner Exception:
SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: RefreshTokens.AccountId'.
```

I thought `RefreshTokens.AccountId` should be generated by the framework. How to rectify the problem?

Comment: I think you should do like this `var newRefreshToken = new RefreshToken
{
    // set other properties of RefreshToken
    AccountId = account.Id // set the AccountId explicitly
};
account.RefreshTokens.Add(newRefreshToken);`

Comment: I can't set `AccountId` explicitly as it is not a member of `RefreshToken`.

Comment: @JanuszDalecki Then how does your `TABLE RefreshTokens` contain a SQL-`NULL`-able column named `AccountId`?

Comment: @JanuszDalecki I just realised that EF incorrectly inferred that from your `class Account` and `class RefreshToken`. This is why we should always specify explicit attributes on EF model members to avoid this. For a start, you should _never_ give entities ambiguous names like `Id` - instead be explicit: use `int AccountId` in `class Account` and `int RefreshTokenId` in `class RefreshToken`.

Comment: @Dai I have not tried yet your solution but thanks for the help.
It has worked for me when I added this code to my DataContext class:
`protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasMany(e => e.RefreshTokens).WithOne(e => e.Account).IsRequired();
        }`
After this I have removed this fix from my code and it still works for some reason. Is there some sort of caching mechanism in EF?